# Framework or tool to prevent too many pending threads and OOM in web applications

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-spark, bigdata

I'm developing a web app using Java/Jetty which provides multiple REST APIs upon a DB. Each REST API creates multiple threads and each thread fetches multiple records from DB. When there are too many concurrent requests, either number of open/pending threads goes behind limits or number of in-memory records causes out of memory (OOM) error and the app crashes. I'm looking for some sort of framework or tool to manage/schedule the processing resources of single/multiple machines:

1. (fair) scheduling of memory/CPU resources among REST API calls
2. check for limitations (max open threads/max used memory) and when they are exceeded queue/pause new API calls (with timeouts) and resume paused calls when resources are available again.

In thread pools (of Java) we could only limit number of concurrent threads globally, so one REST call could reserve all these threads and other calls should wait for this call to be finished, also thread pools won't limit global use of memory.

I'm familiar with Apache Spark, but it also crashes in case of unlimited requests and it's more of an ad-hoc/slow framework not suitable for interactive web applications. Is there any framework in Java or a tool (not required to be written in Java) to do this out of the box?

Comment: Perhaps you should define “OOM”, “og”, etc.

Comment: `In thread pools ... we could only limit number of concurrent threads globally` - no. You limit threads per executor. If you have global executor - the limit is global. If you create executor per request - you limit per request.

Comment: By OOM i mean out of memory due to loading too many loaded DB records that could not be GCed yet.

Comment: As i mentioned in my question, in case of global thread pool, one request may used all threads and other requests would be blocked, in case of per request thread pool, how can i limit number of threads globally (also fair distribution of this maximum threads limit among input requests)?